# Windows10 firmware update or hyper-v causes automatic repair loop everytime

Tags: windows-10, boot, installation, hyper-v, dism

I have an Asus FX705DX laptop (Ryzen 3550H) and i've been having the same issue since i bought it several months ago.
Everytime a new Firmware (BIOS) update from Asus is installed automatically by Windows Update my system runs into an Automatic Repair Loop and nothing i do (startup repair, system restore, uninstall updates) but reinstalling Windows solves the problem.
I also get to this situation with a new windows install and enabling Hyper-V.
This last time i made a clean new installations of Windows 10 1903 Education, installed all updates and then, when i enabled Hyper-V i got into reboot loop again. I ran automatic startup repair and SrtTrail.txt said:

```
**Root cause found: 
---------------------------
A recently serviced boot binary is corrupt.

Repair action: Uninstall latest LCU
Result: Failed. Error code =  0x3713**
```

So i entered command prompt from rescue environment and did a:

```
**DISM /Image:D:\ /ScratchDir:D:\Scratch /Cleanup-Image /RevertPendingActions**
```

which completed successfully and i could restart and, to my surprise, Hyper-V is enabled.

The problem is i tried to enable Hypervisor Platform and shows error "Changes cannot be completed".
I went again to recovery command line and tried to install if from there with:

```
**dism /image:c:\ /scratchdir:c:\scratch /enable-feature /featurename:hypervisorplatform**
```

which gave me error:
[enable-feature hypervisor error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om2Ul.jpg)

Then i did a dism checkhealth and i have:
[checkhealth component store error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mVtf.jpg)

Also, installing VisualStudio i got a warning saying:

```
**Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature,version=16.0.28315.86' failed to install.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=-2146498512
    Details
        Command executed: "C:\Windows\system32\dism.exe" /online /quiet /norestart /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:"netfx4extended-aspnet45" /All /logPath:"C:\Users\mike\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20190811143007_359_Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature.log"
        Return code: -2146498512
        Return code details: Unknown error (0x800f0830)**
```

So i can work with the system but it seems a bit corrupted.

Thanks in advance. Any help would be much appreciated.

I attach links to dism logfiles.
[DISM log 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MGO9qt5lbVAqu5p6LI7jOAMTDLn2RG69/view?usp=sharing)
[DISM log 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wEnwJhk5v3Xgc5cv-9FjDzpudjBp_RWz/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: My apologies, "Windows 10 Education".

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Did a repair install and all is going fine again. See details in
https://www.tenforums.com/showthread.php?t=138320&goto=newpost